# How to unshrink quilted jacket?

Tags: clothing

I am talking about a jacket like this:

[image]

What I did is wash the jacket in the washing machine at 40°C and now the filling in the individual "chambers", holding the padding are not padded any more, because the filling has shrunk.

I seem to remember, that something like this can be fixed, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

This method may or may not work depending on the material filled inside the jacket but there's no harm in trying.
Wash your jacket in normal water again and this time make sure to dry it in the washing machine's dryer for around 10-15 minutes. After this dry it properly in the sun. Keep it hanged in sunlight for 2-3 days. I hope this will make it take its shape again.

Comment: thx, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

My quilted down jacket has washing instructions,  and I have washed it several times successfully by following them.

The important part is to dry it in the dryer with dryer balls. These are special plastic balls with points all over like 3 D hairbrushes, and they beat the filling back into puffiness. They are also useful for pillows etc. If you don't have dryer balls, use some clean tennis balls.